# Why should piping be avoided in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, pipe

Most of the time I see someone suggesting using a pipe in a bash script there is someone pointing out not to use it and instead use only one command.

Example:

```
find $dir -name $pattern
```

instead of

```
ls $dir | grep $pattern
```

Is there another reason than look to avoid pipe?

Comment: you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: You know that there's a difference between the two commands? find also searches subdirectories. ls does not.

Comment: @fancyPants yes, the exact commands I ment would have been "ls $dir | grep -i $pattern" and "find $dir -maxdepth 1 -iname '*$patter*'  -exec basename \{} .po \;" With those you should get the same output but the find command seems much more complicated. But the Question is more about pipes in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pipe create a new process. In your example, ls and grep are two processes and find is one. One or more pipes makes command slower. One trivial example:

```
$ time find Downloads -name *.pdf &>/dev/null

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time ls Downloads | grep pdf &>/dev/null

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: In principle correct, but there are also different semantics. `ls` also sorts the output alphabetically, while `find` just uses the order as returned by the underlying system commands. Additionally, as already pointed out, `find` is recursive.

Comment: you are only `time`-ing `ls` here, not the grep

Comment: @W. Mann: Ah, indeed, for the `bash` `time` builtin, this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with piping per se. What should be avoided is useless `fork()`ing, meaning that starting a process is a relatively time-consuming thing.

If something can be done in one process, that is usually better than using two processes for the same result.

Comment: I would assume that the required `exec` is more costly than `fork`. Does anybody have numbers?

Comment: You can easily test that, but fork() involves creating a new process, copying the current process, using locking and whatnot, while execl simply replaces the current process.

Comment: copying the current process? You have to duplicate the context, but not the memory itself. At least in Linux, `fork` is implemented based on copy-on-write.

Comment: @W.Mann Yes you are correct in that the writable pages are copy-on-write. The page tables linking to them though have to be copied, plus all open file descriptors, etc.